# Atomic structure in C?

Tags: c, atomic, c11

I want to make the entire contents of a small C structure `atomic`, but [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) appears to show that only primitive data types as fields within the struct can be made atomic.

For example, I want to do:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

typedef struct my_obj_s {
  int16_t a;
  int16_t b;
  bool is_initialized;
} my_obj_t;

_Atomic my_obj_t my_atomic_object;
```

but only appear to be able to do:

```
typedef struct my_obj_s {
  atomic_char16_t a;
  atomic_char16_t b;
  atomic_bool is_initialized;
} my_obj_t;
```

Is there no way to achieve atomicity on anything larger than a primitive data type (short of bracketing reads/writes in locks/mutexes/etc)?

Comment: From the doc you are linking: "type-name - any type other than array or function." So yes, you can use _Atomic for structs.

Comment: [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) under `Notes` describes `Accessing a member of an atomic struct/union is undefined behavior.` Using `_Atomic` on the members directly works great for my thread library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to use the `_Atomic` qualifier for structures.

With these structures you then basically only have the restricted possibilities of access through the `atomic_...` type generic functions (or by structure assignment), you can't access the individual fields. The most useful of these functions is probably `atomic_compare_exchange_weak`.

If your structure does not fit into a wide register, platforms usually implement these atomic types by using some kind of lock that is stored outside of your structure. If it does, they use the native capacities of the platform. Such properties may depend on your compiler options, in particular  you'd have to ensure that these are the same for all your compiled objects.

For `gcc` usually `-march=native` triggers the best features for that, for example the use of 128 bit native atomics if they are available.

Comment: How would the structure behave if it is atomic? If A uses an AtomicStruct and is working a longer time on this structure and B wants to access the AtomicStruct at a time A is still using it, would this lead to a dead lock if A uses e.g. a infinite loop on it?

Comment: @mortytheshorty You cannot "work" on an atomic structure, because you can't access individual members. Basically you can only copy it all at once. So usually you copy it to a local variable, do your changes and then copy it back. And for the copy operation you would use the atomic functions which I indicated.